# How many paths of length $4$ are there in $K_{3,7}$?

Tags: graph-theory

Let vertices of bipartite graph $ K_{3,7} $ be $\{A_1\;  A_2\; A_3\}$ and $\{ B_1 \; B_2\; B_3 \; \dots  B_7 \} $.

> Q1. Is $\{A_1\; B_1\; A_2 \; B_2\; A_1\}$ following considered as one of the path?
>   Q2. Is $\{A_1\; B_1\; A_2 \; B_2\; A_1\}$ identical to $\{ B_1\; A_2 \; B_2\; A_1\;B_1\}$?

Comment: The definition of "path" is not always the same.  Sometimes "simple path" (no vertex used twice) is implied, and sometimes not.  ("Walk" always means that vertices may be multiple times; "simple path" always means that they may be used only once; but "path" is ambiguous.)  You need to look at the precise definition you're using.

Comment: For your second question, no, paths have start and end vertices, and different traversals of the same cycle are different paths.

Comment: Let n be a nonnegative integer and G a directed graph.A path of length n from u to v in G is a sequence of edges e1, e2, . . . , en of G such that e1 is associated with (x0, x1), e2 is associated with (x1, x2), and so on, with en associated with (xn−1, xn), where x0 = u and xn = v. When there are no multiple edges in the directed graph, this path is denoted by its vertex sequence x0, x1, x2, . . . , xn. A path of length greater than zero that begins and ends at the same vertex is called a circuit or cycle. A path or circuit is called simple if it does not contain the same edge more than once.

Comment: The above is the definition from my textbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition that you gave in the comments does not require a path to be simple (no edge used twice) and does classify circuits as paths, so $A_1B_1A_2B_2A_1$ is a path of length $4$. It is not identical to $B_1A_2B_2A_1B_1$, because the endpoints of a path are distinguished from the other vertices (if any): the path $A_1B_1A_2B_2A_1$ has initial vertex $A_1$ and final vertex $A_1$, while the path $B_1A_2B_2A_1B_1$ has initial vertex $B_1$ and final vertex $B_1$.

Comment: What if the path should be a simple path? Is $A_1B_1A_2B_2A_1$ a simple path?

Comment: @Callisto: Yes, by the definition that you gave: it has no repeated edge.

Comment: In this case, suppose we need a path of length 5. Then $ B_2A_1B_4A_2B_3A_1$ is also a simple path, right?

Comment: @Callisto: No: you’ve used the edge $\{B_3,A_2\}$ twice.

Comment: Sorry! I meant to type $B_2A_1B_4A_2B_3A_1$

Comment: @Callisto: Yes, that’s simple by the definition that you gave. For some people it would not be simple, on account of the repeated vertex.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: @Callisto: You’re welcome!